# Troubles with singularity of log when trying to plot a function in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to plot the function : log(y-x^2).

I've tried some things like :

```
    clf()
    x=-10:0.001:10
    y=x
    y(find(y <= x.^2)) = %nan
    plot3d(x, y, log(y-x.^2))
```

but it doesn't work.

I've also searched on how to define a set but found no real results.

If you knew either what i do wrong or how i can define a set with a function it would help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "set"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your intention right, you want to plot a "surface". To do this (in one way), you need to define an evenly spaced grid. The easiest way is with `ndgrid`. Then you calculate the "surface" points above this grid.
Try the following code:

```
clf()
x=-10:0.5:10;
y=x;
[xx,yy]=ndgrid(x,y);  //grid coordinates
M=yy-xx.^2;   //the surface points
M(find(M==0))=%nan;   //kill 0s to avoid log singularity
plot3d(x,y,log(M));
```

Another possible way to avoid the singularity, is to define x such way, that M never becomes zero, e.g.:

```
x=-10:0.51:10;
```

This way you won't have "holes" in your surface.

Comment: I tried your solution and then played around and now it works exactly the way i wanted to. I juste do a test to know if the (x,y) value cause an error. Thanks again !